# Given an x,y coordinate, I need to find all html elements underneath it

Tags: javascript, html, position

I am building an app where I repeatedly need to get lists of html elements sitting under a specific location (x,y relative to the viewport, e.g.).  I am considering the following approaches, but none are satisfying:

(1) Go through the html, build a data-structure that keeps track of the x,y position of every element (x,y -> set of elements), and then access this data-structure when I need to do a lookup.  Unfortunately, this approach is a bit cumbersome and I am looking for a better way to solve this problem.  Plus, I fear it may be way too slow.

(2) A probably better approach I am considering is to temporarily add a top-level event handler that captures all hover events, to fake a mouse-hover at the particular position, and then to remove the handler, but it looks like this will only return the top-most element (e.g., if there are a bunch of absolute-position divs over a particular location, I think it will only return the one with the highest z-index, whereas I need all, although I am not sure).

(3) For IE, there is componentFromPoint(x, y), but I can't find an equivalent in other browser -- that and it only returns the top-most element.

Note that the app is built as a bookmarklet and I have no control over the underlying html -- this unfortunately curtails any easy server-side solutions.

I am willing to use libraries (currently on jquery).

FYI, so far the best I have found here is [Getting DIV id based on x & y position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48999/getting-div-id-based-on-x-y-position); wondering if there is something more up-to-date.

Comment: I'm probably being a git - what's your *real* goal? There may be a more elegant solution to the one you're currently investigating.

Comment: Our app allows users to put divs with our content over any webpage.  Because the html of the underlying page can be rendered differently based on factors outside our control (e.g., browser type, or size of the window may change position/alignment of individual elements), we can't position the divs relative to the top/left of the page as a whole (they would appear to sit in a different place based on the viewing environment, which is no good).  Instead, we need to attach the divs to an element which we know does not move (or to an element lying directly underneath the div). Hence the question.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for the [`elementFromPoint`](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#t20) method that exists in MSIE, FF3+ and in some form in Safari and Opera. It may be also worth taking a look at [`getBoundingClientRect`](http://ejohn.org/blog/getboundingclientrect-is-awesome/). Combine the two and you should be in business.

You might also be able to speed up approach #1 by keeping the calculated structure between lookups and only recalculate it when changes actually occur on the page. Take a look at how selector engines (Sizzle in paticular) cache their lookups and expires the cache when the DOM changes.

It may seem contrived, but calculating every element's position is what drag-and-drop handlers have been doing up until now. There are a dozen free ones out there that have this stuff properly optimized (my hunch is that YUI's will have the most readable code). These may be dated though or trying to support browsers that you don't want/need to.

Comment: Thanks. elementFromPoint and componentFromPoint are what I have been looking at.  Not great, but might just have to do with.  Good advice on looking at YUI's implementation of drag-and-drop.