# How do I identify which element (or elements) exist at a specific position?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the vast number of threads/searches that relate to how to obtain coordinates of an element, I'm having a tough time trying to figure out the opposite - how to get the element (or elements) at a specific x y coordinate. Any suggetions?

Comment: could you clarify your question? maybe some code? Which data structure are you using, and the context of the problem?

Comment: You'd probably have to loop through all the elements and check if their area include that point.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Locating DOM element by absolute coordinates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786066/locating-dom-element-by-absolute-coordinates)

Answer (score 1):

Well, for start you could itarete trough all of the elements in the body section:

```
$('body').find('*')
```

Then check if the corresponding element is at that position, if its there do stuff...
Of course, if your html tags are overlapping, then you will have lots of result, wich you can filter checking parents-childs... u get the idea.