# coordinates of a <div> using JS

Tags: javascript, html, coordinates

I would like to get the coordinates of a , but I cant figure how to do that. I tried using style.scrollTop, style.top but I cannot retrieve anything... In my function posX = undefined and posXX == nada

I would appreciate some help from you.

Code:

```
<html>
<title>
YOP
</title>

<head>
<style TYPE="text/css"> 
<!--
  div.background{
    width:450px;
    height:450px;
    background:url(plasmid.jpg) no-repeat;
    border:2px solid black; 
  }

  div.transbox{
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  margin:5px 5px;
  background-color:#ff0000;
  border:1px solid black;
  /* for IE */
  filter:alpha(opacity=60);
  /* CSS3 standard */
  opacity:0.6;
  cursor: move;
  }

-->
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" >    

function MoveIt(){

     obj = document.getElementById("arect");

     posX = obj.style.scrollTop;
     posXX = obj.style.top;
     alert("x:"+posX + " xx:"+posXX);     
}
</script>

</head>

<body bgcolor="white" >

<div class="background" id="MyDiv2">  
  <div id="arect" name="arect" class="transbox" onmousedown="MoveIt();" >
  </div>           
</div>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48999/getting-div-id-based-on-x-y-position Not the same, but will lead you into the right path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky one, different browsers implement it very differently, you may have to take scrolling and other factors into consideration. I would reccomend using a library (such as jQuery), they have solved the x-browser issues for us already.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will have a look